# How can I improve unioning iteration

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, union

Im trying to make a effective look up on the database, but struggling. The following snippet is generated from a stored procedure which loops through all the categories and fieldnames. The problem is I need the top 1 lookup based upon the priorty. The other problem is I now need to extend this to do multiple locations not just one, which it is doing from my .net code at the moment, in order to make it more efficient.

Any advice would help, thanks

```
DECLARE @ApplicationProviderId INT
SET @ApplicationProviderId = 3
DECLARE @LocationId BIGINT
SET @LocationId = 928502
DECLARE @CategoryId INT
SET @CategoryId = 502
SELECT  sub.VolatileLocationContentId, sub.ContentProviderId, sub.CategoryId, sub.FieldName, sub.Value  --, sub.*
    FROM
        (SELECT     TOP 1 vlc.VolatileLocationContentId, vlc.ContentProviderId, vlc.CategoryId, vlc.FieldName, vlc.Value

        FROM            [VolatileLocationContent] vlc

        INNER JOIN  [ApplicationProviderContentProviderVolatileLocationContentField] apcpvlc
        ON          vlc.ContentProviderId = apcpvlc.ContentProviderId
        AND         vlc.FieldName = apcpvlc.FieldName

        WHERE           apcpvlc.ApplicationProviderId = @ApplicationProviderId
        AND         LocationId = @LocationId
        AND         vlc.FieldName = 'DescriptionStandard'
        AND         NOT vlc.Value IS null AND           vlc.CategoryId = @CategoryId                AND         vlc.DeactivatedOn IS NULL
        ORDER BY    apcpvlc.Priority
        ) sub
UNION
            SELECT  sub.VolatileLocationContentId, sub.ContentProviderId, sub.CategoryId, sub.FieldName, sub.Value  --, sub.*
    FROM
        (SELECT     TOP 1 vlc.VolatileLocationContentId, vlc.ContentProviderId, vlc.CategoryId, vlc.FieldName, vlc.Value

        FROM            [VolatileLocationContent] vlc

        INNER JOIN  [ApplicationProviderContentProviderVolatileLocationContentField] apcpvlc
        ON          vlc.ContentProviderId = apcpvlc.ContentProviderId
        AND         vlc.FieldName = apcpvlc.FieldName

        WHERE           apcpvlc.ApplicationProviderId = @ApplicationProviderId
        AND         LocationId = @LocationId
        AND         vlc.FieldName = 'Image1'
        AND         NOT vlc.Value IS null AND           vlc.CategoryId = @CategoryId                AND         vlc.DeactivatedOn IS NULL
        ORDER BY    apcpvlc.Priority
        ) sub
```

Comment: If you want result for multiple location, will you send comma separated locations ?

Comment: How it is possible to get top result based on priority and also the operation will be incorporating multiple location? You should always get one row only.

Comment: I can use a CSV of location Ids or a table of them. Im not sure about how to improve the top 1 query, hence the post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @ApplicationProviderId INT;
SET @ApplicationProviderId = 3;
DECLARE @LocationId BIGINT;
SET @LocationId = 928502;
DECLARE @CategoryId INT;
SET @CategoryId = 502;
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT     vlc.VolatileLocationContentId, vlc.ContentProviderId,
               vlc.CategoryId, vlc.FieldName, vlc.Value,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vlc.FieldName
                                      ORDER BY apcpvlc.Priority) AS rownum
    FROM       [VolatileLocationContent] vlc
    INNER JOIN [ApplicationProviderContentProviderVolatileLocationContentField] apcpvlc
    ON         vlc.ContentProviderId = apcpvlc.ContentProviderId
    AND        vlc.FieldName = apcpvlc.FieldName

    WHERE      apcpvlc.ApplicationProviderId = @ApplicationProviderId
    AND        LocationId = @LocationId
    AND        vlc.FieldName IN ('DescriptionStandard', 'Image1')
    AND        NOT vlc.Value IS null
    AND        vlc.CategoryId = @CategoryId
    AND        vlc.DeactivatedOn IS NULL
)
SELECT
  sub.VolatileLocationContentId,
  sub.ContentProviderId,
  sub.CategoryId,
  sub.FieldName,
  sub.Value
FROM sub
WHERE sub.rownum = 1
```